# Similar matrix of $M\in\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{C})$,

Tags: matrices, similar-matrices

Let $M\in\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{C})$, Show that $M$ is similar with a matrix having one of the following forms:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
z_1 & 0 \\
0 & z_2
\end{pmatrix}
~,~\text{with }(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
z & 1 \\
0 & z 
\end{pmatrix}
~,~\text{with }z\in\mathbb{C}
$$
An idea please

Comment: Is there an answer without going to the notion of eigenvalues?

Comment: Why do you ask? Even the result you wrote has eigenvalues $z_1,z_2$ and $z$. Avoiding eigenvalues in linear algebra is like avoiding prime numbers in number theory.

Answer (score 0):

A complex endomorphism $f$ is triangularizable since $\mathbb{C}$ is an algebraically closed field. Hence, the matrix that represents it with respect to e.g. the canonical basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$ is similar to a triangular matrix. There are two cases to consider:

- the eigenvalues of $f$ are different:in this cases you can diagonalize $f$, and so you are in the first "form" of your question;
- $f$ has a unique eigenvalue $z$: you have to distinguish two subcases now. If the geometric multiplicity of $z$ is equal to 2, we are back to the first "form" with $z_1=z_2=z$; otherwise, if the geometric multiplicity is equal to $1$, the eigenspace relative to $z$ has dimension 1, spanned by a vector $v$. Let $\{v, w\}$ be a basis which respect to the endomorphism $f$ has the form

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
z & x \\
0 & z
\end{pmatrix},
$$

where $x \neq 0$. Now you have only to change the basis in order to replace $x$ with $1$, which is an easy exercise.